# How can I fit backgroundimage to master div?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I want to try a background image under canvas. however, when I set the size to 100%, the image is invisible.

How can I solve this?

I want to have a background image at 100% on every screen.

```css
#bodyy {
  background: url(a.jpg);
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.active {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="bodyy">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: and also... you have can try to move the css definitions from #bodyy to body

Comment: Have you tried setting `width` and `height` properties of your `#bodyy` or setting the background for the `body` itself?

Comment: why creating a div with id body and not using THE body ?

Comment: yes I tried the body, then I change the div.

Answer (score 1):

To make the image take the whole screen, you need to set the height of body to be at least `100vh`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/1000/800/);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a background image to a container with zero height, you have to add height or minimum height to this container since it has no content.

On the other hand, you can use background-size: cover or contain to fit your background image to the viewport.

```css
#bodyy {
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/622/220/arch);
  background-size: cover; /* or contain */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* you have to add height to this container since it has no content*/
  height: 100vh;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  /* display: none; */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="bodyy">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

check out this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hadabo/622rzdra/3/